# How to save a 2-3-4-Tree in ormlite (android)

Tags: java, android, tree, ormlite

I want to save a structure like this

```
RootTree --- CourseTree --- SemesterTree --- SubjectTree --- LearningGroups
   |---CouTree2..  |--SemTree2..  |...          |...
   |---CouTree3..  |--SemTree3..
```

All the trees inherit from the same parent 234Tree and have an `ArrayList<234Tree> children`

What would be the best way to do that using ormlite for android?

I already tried to add the

```
@DatabaseTable{tableName="CourseTree"}
```

as a test, but it tells me

```
No annotations allowed here
```

(Thought I added ormlite to the gradle script and imported the needed packages)